# Hide DIV and show image on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using jQuery I need to hide a DIV and show an image when the Submit button on a form is clicked.

The relevant part of the HTML is below:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <div id="submitDiv" class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-1">
                    <button id="Submit" name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div id="SpinWheelDiv" class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-1">
                    <img id="SpinWheel" height="20px" src="../img/spin.gif" hidden="">
                </div>
        </div>
```

The jQuery script being used is below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#formCForm').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        $('#SpinWheel').removeAttr('hidden');
        $('#submitDiv').attr("hidden","true");
        return true;
    }
  });
 </script>
```

The problem is that when return is set for false this works on both Safari and Chrome. With the return set to true it does not work on Safari anymore. Strangely enough if a put an alert("Hello") before the return Safari does show the alert but fails to hide the div and show the image.

On Chrome everything works as expected.

Maybe I should add that I am using Bootstrap along with [Bootstrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

Any ideas please?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle of your codes, not sure what are you asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$('#submitDiv').attr("hidden","hidden");
```

instead of using

```
$('#submitDiv').attr("hidden","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write following code to show an element.

```
 $('#submitDiv').show();
```

To show or hide best and easy way is to use method `.show() and .hide()`

Answer (score 0):

`e.isDefaultPrevented()` by the jQuery API's definition is only `true` when you `e.preventDefault();`

I'm not sure if this checks does what you want, but if you don't prevent the default behavior of your submit button; it will trigger an action on the above laying `<form>` which usually results in a page refresh.

Do `e.preventDefault()` and start handling your form from there.